# c++ vector<Book*> title being a string

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm doing an university project on a library.

The class `Book` is used on data so I thought of creating a vector with pointers to the objects `Book`'s. The problem is, I need to read an input file with the data and then create a `Book` to add to the `vector<Book*>` catalog.

Whenever I do so, the `getline()` with integers works fine, but as soon as I try to save a string data to the `Book`, such as `Title`, I get a total different string of characters instead of the desirable title, or worse, an error.

```cpp
#ifndef LIBRARY_PROGRAM_BOOK_H
#define LIBRARY_PROGRAM_BOOK_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Person.h"

class Book
{
public:
    //Book(std::string title, int id, );
    Book() {};
    ~Book(){};
    void setTitle(std::string title);
    std::string getTitle() const;
    void setBookId(int bookId);
    int getBookId() const;
    void setOwner(int owner);
    int getOwner() const;
    void setCategory(std::string category);
    std::string getCategory() const;
    void setValue(float value);
    float getValue() const;
    void setLoanFee(float loanFee);
    float getLoanFee() const;
    void setIsBorrowed(bool isBorrowed);
    bool getIsBorrowed() const;
    void setBeginOfLoan(int beginOfLoan);
    int getBeginOfLoan() const;
    void setMaximumLoanTime(int maximumLoanTime);
    int getMaximumLoanTime() const;
    void setEndOfLoan(int EndOfLoan);
    int getEndOfLoan() const;
    int getLoanTimeRemaining() const;
    void addRating(float rating);
    float getRating() const;
    void addComment(std::string comment);
    std::vector<std::string> getComments() const;
    //void addToWaitingList(Person* person);
    //bool removeFromWaitingList(Person* person);
    //void sortWaitingList();

private:
    std::string title; /**Book title*/
    int bookId; /**Book id*/
    int owner; /**Id from the book owner*/
    std::string category; /**Book category, i.e. Fiction, Drama, Police, ...*/
    float value; /**Book value*/
    float loanFee; /** Book loan fee*/
    bool isBorrowed; /** Boolean variable containing if the book is borrowed or not, true if yes, no otherwise*/
    int beginOfLoan; /**Will be set to 0 if book is not loaned in the moment */
    int maximumLoanTime; /**Max time that a book should be loaned, should be defined by the book owner*/
    int endOfLoan; /**Will be set to 0 if book is not loaned in the moment */
    std::vector<float> ratings; /**Vector containing all the ratings given by the readers*/
    std::vector<std::string> comments; /**Vector containing all the comments given by the readers*/
    //std::vector<Person*> waitingList; /**Vector containing who is waiting to read the book*/
    bool isLost; /** Boolean variable containing if the book is lost or not, true if yes, no otherwise*/
};

#endif //LIBRARY_PROGRAM_BOOK_H
```

This is the code where I read the file, create a `Book`, and add it to the catalog:

```cpp
std::ifstream books_file ("../Books.txt");

// adding books to the catalog
while(!books_file.eof()) {
    Book book;
    std::getline(books_file, input);
    if(books_file.eof()) break;
    book.setTitle(input);
    std::getline(books_file, input);
    book.setBookId(std::stoi(input));
    std::getline(books_file, input);
    book.setOwner(std::stoi(input));
    catalog.push_back(&book);
}
books_file.close();
```

Does it have to do with the way I'm using pointers?

I tried doing `vector<Book>` instead of `vector<Book*>` and it works perfectly.

What am I not seeing right?

**EDIT**: error on Clion:

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: uge = huge? `std::vector` already dynamically allocates its memory (and manages it for you), storing pointers in a vector will not save any space or allocations, it rather makes everything more complicated

Comment: why do you store pointers in the vector?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons

Comment: the books will be destroyed when they go out of scope, you store invalid pointers in the vector

Comment: _Does it have to do with the way I'm using pointers?_ Yes it does, for the reason given in the preceding comment.

Comment: `while(!books_file.eof())` is another bug. Details at [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons). The code tries to hack around it with `if(books_file.eof()) break;`, bit this allows an EOF after that point to sneak through. Plus it's only looking for EOF and there are many more things in addition to EOF to trip over.

Comment: I highly recommend not using pointers.  Use `std::vector<Book>` instead.  Pointers will complicate the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(!books_file.eof()) {
    Book book; <--------- stack allocated variable
    std::getline(books_file, input);
    if(books_file.eof()) break;
    book.setTitle(input);
    std::getline(books_file, input);
    book.setBookId(std::stoi(input));
    std::getline(books_file, input);
    book.setOwner(std::stoi(input));
    catalog.push_back(&book); <------- take address of stack allocation
} <----------- destroy stack allocation, making the address invalid
```

Solutions

make the vector contain books instead of pointers, if the vector is huge you will get hit by some copying/moving.

make a heap allocated copy of the book.

**untested code**

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Book>> catalog.


auto book = std::make_unique<Book>(/* insert data for constructor of Book */);
catalog.emplace_back(std::move(book));
```

Using unique_ptr so the books gets destroyed when catalog does.

Comment: This complexity can be eliminated by not using dynamic memory.  Using `push_back()` will make a copy of the object and place into vector.

Comment: I'll be better off by using vector<Book> then, thank you for the perfect explanation!!
I have another vector<Person*>, the difference is that I can add child classes like Member and Non Member, why when I create a NonMember* and Member*, add it to the vector, doesn't it happen the same? Is it because of polymorphism?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The Book is a rather big structure and every reallocation will cause substantial copying, only a measuring can tell if its worth it.

Comment: @JoãoPedro you need the pointer when storing polymporphic objects because if you store the base class as a value, all of the derived class's extras [get sliced away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) to make the derived class fit into the base class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root of your issue is that you create a `Book` right below the `while` line, take it's address when you put it in the vector, but then that `Book` immediately goes out of scope when you hit the `}` so it's destroyed and the pointer is pointing at essentially random memory. If you want to store a pointer to it you should allocate it on the heap via `Book* book = new Book;`. But as others have pointed out, you'd probably be better off storing the `Book` itself or a `unique_ptr<Book>` in your `vector` instead of raw pointers.